# Strapi CMS: Add calculated field

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I am trying to use and learn Strapi Headless CMS while implementing it in a small company. I need to calculate some fields and display it in the form (while filling fields) and table.

I was looking in the model life cycle but I did not find any cicle regarding input changes, just the model.

I have tried `beforeSave` cycle but it is obviously triggered after an user clicks on Save button, but according to [their own documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/models.html#lifecycle-callbacks) should work:

```js
beforeSave: async (model, attrs, options) => {
    model.set('FinalCost', attrs.budget- attrs.cost);
}
```

This code doesn't work, but I am trying to show how the `finalCost` field, after filling `cost` and `budget` should look like (in real time). I also tried `attrs.FinalCost = attrs.budget - attrs.cost` but nothing changes.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

#### Edit:

I had to verify that `budget` field were truthy before setting `FinalCost`:

```js
beforeSave: async (model, attrs, options) => {
    if (attrs.FinalCost) {
       attrs.FinalCost = attrs.budget- attrs.cost;
    }
}
```

But this does not answer my first issue, that this should work in real time and bot until I press "Save" button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some resources that will help you.

Model's life cycles function are called when an entry is created/update/...

So in your case `FinalCost` is an attribute of your model and its value will be updated and saved any times your update your entry.

This is the same system as in this guide - https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/guides/slug.html

If you don't want to store the value is a field, you will have to update the API controller to calculate the value on the fly.

That is done in this guide - https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/guides/custom-data-response.html